# Definition of multiplicity of intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading this [paper](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Stohr-Voloch.pdf) and I don't know this definition in page 3:

[image]

What is the definition of multiplicity of the intersection of a hyperplane $H$ at a point $P$ in a curve $X$?

**Remark:** My only background is Fulton's Algebraic curves.

Thanks in advance